# Cross domain JSON POST

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

As a newbie I have read hundreds of post on various forums that state that cross domain JSON POSTs are not possible unless you use proxies, iframes. jsonp (only supports GET) or modify the server (Access-Control-Allow Origin).

None of these seems to be correct because tools like RESTClient for Firefox is definitely doing cross domain POSTs without any server modification.

The following jsp code runs fine if I run it on the same domain / IP address as the php server (_szFileRequest is the full URL and reqData is JSON Stringify JSON array information)

```
jQuery.ajax('' + _szFileRequest,
    {
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        data: reqData,
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json",
```

If I run this exact same code on another web server (on the same subnet but effectively a 'different domain' to the php server) I have to change to

```
contentType: 'text/plain; charset=utf-8',
```

as otherwise OPTIONS is returned by the server, instead of POST. Unfortunately text/plain then causes issues with the returned JSON which fails JSON:parse as you would expect.

Plugging the initial code into Firefox's RESTClient works as it should.

I am totally confused (you clearly can do cross-domain jquery.ajax POSTs without any server modifications) and would appreciate any feedback on this (you may need to send some pre-flight headers or something, tools like Fiddler do not seem to show exactly what RESTClient is sending).

Regards
Active

Comment: RESTClient is a browser addon. It doesn't have the same security restrictions that web sites have.

Comment: I would not expect a valid JSON string to fail a JSON.parse when returned as text/plain

Comment: Not all API's are accessible directly using ajax from browser...end of story

Comment: @Juhana or more clearly , restrictions that browsers have

Comment: Or more accurately, the browsers don't impose the same restrictions to addons. Naturally the browser could send the request, it just doesn't allow it.

Comment: Note that the server and the client are running on the same machine (mine), the RESTClient works and correctly POSTs, the jsp results in an OPTIONS reponse from the server unless I change contentType to text/plain.

Comment: Fiddler does show 1 difference, for RESTClient                                                                                        Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8                                                    jsp                                                                                                      Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01 even though I have nothing in my jsp specifying any headers (unless jquery.ajax is adding this.

Comment: Machine doesn't really matter...you are likely using different ports to serve page and ajax data. Implement CORS in server script and problem goes away

Comment: Thanks charlietfl, I was wondering whether anyone knew how Firefox RESTClient manages to 'bypass CORS' and connect to my server and POST without issue. I will examine their code. Regards, Active.